# Windows 7 ipv4 autoconfiguration - cannot connect to internet

Tags: ipv4

I get my internet connection from a guy (lets call him my service provider henceforth). He gives internet connections to many students here in my hostel. My PC gets a private IP through his DHCP server. Now, when I switch on my WiFi, my PC gets a private IP as it should and I can connect to the internet just fine. But now when I connect my LAN cable, my PC gets some "Autoconfiguration IPv4 address" 169.254.110.154(Preferred) and I cannot connect to the internet. Here is the ipconfig /all output for ethernet port:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Marvell Yukon 88E8059 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : <<MAC DISPLAYED HERE>>
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5054:a347:7d06:6e9a%11(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.110.154(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 285222078
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-14-50-AC-68-54-42-49-EE-52-16
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I also tried:

```
Start a command prompt as admin.
Run "netsh winsock reset"
Run "netsh interface ipv4 reset"
Run "netsh interface ipv6 reset"
Restart your computer.
```

All this does not work. Any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi aledovsky,
yes, my service provider gives me both wired and wireless.
All connections - wired or wireless - have to take IP from DHCP server.
Also, I did not switch computer. Infact my WiFi card got damaged so I bought a new WiFi adapter. But wireless is running fine. Problem is with wired!

Comment: Any help from anyone??

Comment: ISSUE SOLVED!
Hi all
Thank you all for your replies.
However the problem was with DHCP server itself.
I had to go and personally force my service provider guy to check his DHCP configuration. He had made a wrong mapping between MAC and IP address and so my machine was using auto-configuration address.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution! Please post this as an answer to your question and then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was the problem with my Internet Provider. It was a DHCP configuration problem. Probably he had mapped the same IP to 2 different MAC addresses or something. I only know that the problem was in configuration of DHCP server on the service providers side. So in future if anyone gets this kind of problem, be sure to check your DHCP configuration of mapping between MAC and IP address first.