# how to enable 'Properties' button of TCP/IPv4 in Network connections in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, tcpip, properties

In the Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections, I have a Wireless Network Connection. When I right-click on it, a properties dialog opens. Now, I need to change the IP address for TCP/IPv4. But the Properties button is disabled.

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/ymse6uo5hhtvqry/tcp-properties-disabled.png]

I tried following commands:

- netsh int ip reset
- netsh winsock reset
- netsh interface IPV4 uninstall
- netsh interface IPV4 install

but did not help.

My issue resembles [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/471925/windows-7-ipv4-autoconfiguration-cannot-connect-to-internet), but I m not sure it is due to DHCP configuration of my ISP provider. Because the internet is working on another computer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you've tried restarting your computer and router, but try

"netsh ipv4 reset",
"netsh ipv6 reset",
"ipconfig /release",
"ipconfig /renew", and
"ipconfig /flushdns"

THEN restart your computer.

If that doesn't work, then refer to this thread: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/tcpipv4-properties-button-disabled/347899fa-b60a-40a3-ad2c-78ef5e0dca37

As it suggests a malware infestation of the "c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys" file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found the solution ([source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-do-i-enable-tcpipv4-properties-button/8a634fc8-630e-48a6-a629-0ebf04585927)) by disabling a service called `datamngr`

It is most probably is caused by AdWare so you should run [AdwCleaner](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/)

To resolve the problem:

1. Click on start type `msconfig` then go to Services tab and find `Datamngr Coordinator`
2. Uncheck it select OK and then reboot your PC.
3. Now IPv4 and IPv6 properties should be enabled.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with build 10049. No way to set up any static IP.

However I used the following solution:
Manually assigned IP address in your router DHCP server for the MAC address of your computer network adapter.

Fixed!

Comment: This sounds like a nice workaround, but reading the other answers I wonder if this doesn't hide the cause, which apparently might be that IPv6 is on and supported, or worse: malware? So, did you read [the link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/tcpipv4-properties-button-disabled/347899fa-b60a-40a3-ad2c-78ef5e0dca37) from dadda7860's answer?

Comment: I assume this answer is about Windows 10. In that case, it doesn’t apply here. Also, this “workaround” (if you even call it that) is simply pointless. There are more (important) settings hidden in that menu.

Answer (score -4):

install malwarebytes free version or other software to remove the malware from your computer run the software to clean the malware on the computer - restart computer after finish cleaning the malware.